# Select inside of Select-New with Linq-To-Sql

Tags: gridview, linq-to-sql, devexpress

I have a GridView which is bound to a LinqServerModeDataSource. In the onSelecting-Event I handle the select manually. It is a join over few Tables an I need to get some Informations from another Table inside the Select.

I am trying like this:

```
e.QueryableSource = (from leistungsklasse in db.leistungsklasse
                                     where leistungsklasse.deletedFlag == 0
                                     // INNER-JOINs
                                     join leistungsklassetyp in db.leistungsklassetyp on leistungsklasse.errechneteKlasse_id equals leistungsklassetyp.id
                                     join person in db.person on leistungsklasse.person_id equals person.id
                                     // auswahl eingrenzen und spalten definieren
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         verbandsnummer = person.verbandsMitgliedsNummer,
                                         dsa = person.dsaAusweisnummer,
                                         leistungsklasseTyp_errechnet_name = leistungsklassetyp.name,
                                         leistungsklasseTyp_erechnet_id = leistungsklasse.errechneteKlasse_id,
                                         leistungsklasseTyp_beantragt_id = leistungsklasse.beantragteKlasse_id,
                                         kennzeichen_errechnet = leistungsklassetyp.kennzeichen,
                                         kennzeichen_beantragt = (from leistungsklassetyp in db.leistungsklassetyp where leistungsklassetyp.id == leistungsklasse.beantragteKlasse_id select leistungsklassetyp.kennzeichen),
                                         // SNIPPET: SELECT IM SELECT
                                         leistungsklasseTyp_beantragt_name = (from leistungsklassetyp in db.leistungsklassetyp where leistungsklassetyp.id == leistungsklasse.beantragteKlasse_id select leistungsklassetyp.name),
                                         leistungsklasse_von = leistungsklasse.von,
                                         leistungsklasse_bis = leistungsklasse.bis,
                                         leistungsklassetyp_errechnet_von = leistungsklassetyp.von,
                                         leistungsklassetyp_errechnet_bis = leistungsklassetyp.bis,
                                         leistungsklassetyp_beantragt_von = (from leistungsklassetyp in db.leistungsklassetyp where leistungsklassetyp.id == leistungsklasse.beantragteKlasse_id select leistungsklassetyp.von),
                                         leistungsklassetyp_beantragt_bis = (from leistungsklassetyp in db.leistungsklassetyp where leistungsklassetyp.id == leistungsklasse.beantragteKlasse_id select leistungsklassetyp.bis),
                                         nurBeantragte = leistungsklassetyp.nurBeantragte,
                                         bogen = leistungsklassetyp.bogen,
                                         vorname = person.vorname,
                                         nachname = person.nachname,
                                         geburtsdatum = person.geburtsdatum,
                                         id = (leistungsklasse.id.ToString() + "-") + (leistungsklasse.person_id.ToString())
                                     });
```

The stapled "from..." inside the select-new give not the Data I expect.

Can someone tell me how get this running?

Answer (score 0):

After testing around about this problem, i got it:

```
e.QueryableSource = (from leistungsklasse in db.leistungsklasse
                                     where leistungsklasse.deletedFlag == 0
                                     // INNER-JOINs
                                     join leistungsklassetyp in db.leistungsklassetyp on leistungsklasse.errechneteKlasse_id equals leistungsklassetyp.id
                                     join person in db.person on leistungsklasse.person_id equals person.id
                                     // auswahl eingrenzen und spalten definieren
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         verbandsnummer = person.verbandsMitgliedsNummer,
                                         dsa = person.dsaAusweisnummer,
                                         leistungsklasseTyp_errechnet_name = leistungsklassetyp.name,
                                         leistungsklasseTyp_erechnet_id = leistungsklasse.errechneteKlasse_id,
                                         leistungsklasseTyp_beantragt_id = leistungsklasse.beantragteKlasse_id,
                                         kennzeichen_errechnet = leistungsklassetyp.kennzeichen,
                                         kennzeichen_beantragt = (from leistungsklassetyp in db.leistungsklassetyp where leistungsklassetyp.id == leistungsklasse.beantragteKlasse_id select new { leistungsklassetyp.kennzeichen }).FirstOrDefault().kennzeichen,
                                         // SNIPPET: SELECT IM SELECT
                                         leistungsklasseTyp_beantragt_name = (from leistungsklassetyp in db.leistungsklassetyp where leistungsklassetyp.id == leistungsklasse.beantragteKlasse_id select new { leistungsklassetyp.name }).FirstOrDefault().name,
                                         leistungsklasse_von = leistungsklasse.von,
                                         leistungsklasse_bis = leistungsklasse.bis,
                                         leistungsklassetyp_errechnet_von = leistungsklassetyp.von,
                                         leistungsklassetyp_errechnet_bis = leistungsklassetyp.bis,
                                         leistungsklassetyp_beantragt_von = (from leistungsklassetyp in db.leistungsklassetyp where leistungsklassetyp.id == leistungsklasse.beantragteKlasse_id select new { leistungsklassetyp.von }).FirstOrDefault().von,
                                         leistungsklassetyp_beantragt_bis = (from leistungsklassetyp in db.leistungsklassetyp where leistungsklassetyp.id == leistungsklasse.beantragteKlasse_id select new { leistungsklassetyp.bis }).FirstOrDefault().bis,
                                         nurBeantragte = leistungsklassetyp.nurBeantragte,
                                         bogen = leistungsklassetyp.bogen,
                                         vorname = person.vorname,
                                         nachname = person.nachname,
                                         geburtsdatum = person.geburtsdatum,
                                         id = (leistungsklasse.id.ToString() + "-") + (leistungsklasse.person_id.ToString())
                                     });
            }
```